# php mysql, how to get total time?

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table that has users, the pages that they visited , session id and time they spent on each page.

```
session_id | talentnum    | page_name    | time
008873e0   | user1        | test.php     | 1311630222
008873e0   | user1        | test.php     | 1311630215
008873e0   | user1        | index.php    | 1311630222
008873e3   | user2        | test.php     | 1311630216
008873e3   | user2        | index.php    | 1311895032
```

how to find ouy how much time a user spent on each session

i think i should find how much the user spent on each page in a session then add the time?? i'm a bit confuze

edit. the time is the time() when they enter that page

any ideas? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, get a list of visitors:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( sesssion_id ) as session FROM _yourTable_;
```

Then perform another query to get the start and end times of each visit:

```
SELECT MIN(time) as START_TIME, MAX_TIME(time) as END_TIME WHERE session_id = '$desired_session';
```

Then, retrieve the results via PHP and subtract the start time from the end time to get the total length of the visit.

Comment: @Dalen: The OP wants to find the total session time, which can be identified by comparing the timestamp of the first hit to the timestamp of the last hit. The time spent on individual pages is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
select distinct(session_id), max(time) - min(time) from test group by session_id
```

Then you have it grouped by session_id. To have it grouped by user:

```
select distinct(talentnum), max(time) - min(time) from test group by talentnum
```